# How can i delete the mysql process which is not used any more?

Tags: mysql, linux

How can i delete the mysql process which is not used any more?

I am creating 1000 sql connection and some are not in use any more. I want to delete all the unused process.

Comment: I don't think a 'process' and 'connection' are the same thing. If you are creating the connections then only you know when they are no longer in use. It sounds like you need to use a connection pool.

Comment: You should close your connection when they are not needed. Killing the processes is not a good way to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should modify the client application so it closes its connections when they are not needed.

Leaving connections open for a long time is usually counter-productive, it's often done as a (misguided, premature) optimisation. It causes problems because:

- Connections are not stateless, and unexpected state causes problems
- Connections get closed by the server after a while, or from network problems, leading to "morning bugs".

It is much better to close connections as soon as you're finished with them, in the general case.

Answer (score 1):

you can list all active connections using the **show processlist** statement, and then kill the ones you don't need using the command **kill {connectionid}** . as others have pointed out, this is not a thing you should do often, instead try to fix the application so that unused connections are closed correctly.

Comment: There is a way we can kill mysql connections which are not used. Like server send a notification to mysql process queue, if there wont be any acknowledgement back to server, server will manually kill that process.

Answer (score 0):

This command will restart the server and close all open connections:
`/etc/init.d/mysqld restart`

You may however want to look into why the connections have not been closed in the first place. Your program is not supposed to leave 1000 connections unclosed.

Comment: I didn't asked how to restart mysql.

that can be soo many connection if we left the connection without closing.